# Kotlin Compiler error e: error: cannot access Hide

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, firebase-mlkit

I tried to add MLKit to my gradle and I get the error:

```
error: cannot access Hide
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Hide not found
```

Gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1"
implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.2"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ??

Comment: Try updating these libraries to the latest versions? Also see <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921843/cannot-access-hide-class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-common-internal-hide-n>.