# Cannot access Hide, class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Hide not found

Tags: android

While building my native android app in android studio getting below error.

"error: cannot access Hide
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Hide not found"

App Details: I have created android library project and added to one of my app as module. In the gradle of library project, so many dependecies are there which is also available in the app label gradle.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, it was because of multiple versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services apis dependency in the app gradle file.

Comment: I fixed it by updating my google and firebase libraries to the latest versions in build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a file Hide.java in your project path: ..\app\src\main\java\com\google\android\gms\common\internal

Source:

```
package com.google.android.gms.common.internal;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PACKAGE })
public @interface Hide {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove multiple versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services apis dependency in the app gradle file and check for other library modules also.

Answer (score 0):

On April 10, 2018, Google deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs were removed on May 29, 2019, and currently any calls to those APIs can be expected to fail. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the migration guide to learn more.